# Problem starting rviz with OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS. As I am trying to start rviz following the tutorial, I receive this error message right after issuing "rosrun rviz rviz". Please help me if you know the solution. Thanks.

Tuan

Failed to initialize Ogre: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library Plugin_CgProgramManager.  System Error: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)
[ERROR] [1311070723.641349333]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library Plugin_CgProgramManager.  System Error: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10638/problem-starting-rviz-with-ogre-exception(7:internalerrorexception)/) by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of: http://answers.ros.org/question/1503/rivzogre-crash-after-update

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1